# Query sharepoint list data in sql server

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, sql-server, sharepoint-list, open-source

I am trying to query sharepoint lists data with sql server,for performance reasons.
Is there any tool to help me do this?
I heard about spud and SPViews but i am searching for something open source or maybe a work around.

Comment: Querying SharePoint databases directly is not supported. Can you expand on what you are attempting to accomplish? All queries need to leverage a supported SharePoint API.

Comment: the API is very low to get large chunks of data that is why i want to customize how i get list data

Comment: Use CSOM which will only grab a minimal set of data plus the data you select. Querying databases directly is not supported.

Comment: i will try that but there is some tools like SPViews or axioworks (https://www.axioworks.com/sqlist/) that do the job

Comment: Any tool that access the database directly is performing an unsupported operation. Use at your own risk. SPViews, if you add the view to the database, will likely result in a database that cannot be updated by patches or version to version upgrades.

Comment: it is recomanded to directly interact with SharePoint Point data base instead you can use rest , csom sdk, or pnp js